# Did the United States Holocaust Museum have a display entitled "Early Warning Signs of Facism"?

Tags: quotes, museums

I saw this on my Facebook news feed, posted on a page called “Truth in Crisis”.  Is this a real display in the United States Holocaust Museum as the post claims?  I’m doubtful as a number of them seem more like a comment on current political and social issues.

[image: Facebook post says "From a display in the United States Holocaust Museum. I wanna see this go viral on every social media outlet yet invented." with photo of paper under display glass]

Text version:

> ### Early Warning Signs of Fascism
>
> - Powerful and continuing nationalism
> - Disdain for human rights
> - Identification of enemies
> - Supremacy of the military
> - Rampant sexism
> - Controlled mass media
> - Obsession with national security
> - Religion and government intertwined
> - Corporate power protected
> - Labor power suppressed
> - Disdain for intellectuals & the arts
> - Obsession with crime & punishment
> - Rampant cronyism & corruption

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to [Snopes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/holocaust-museum-warning-signs-fascism/), this list was sold in the **gift shop** of the Holocaust Museum at one point, although it's no longer sold there (it was **never an exhibit**):

> Sarah Rose, who first shared the photograph on social media, confirmed to us that she took the picture in the museum’s gift shop. We reached out to the USHHM to confirm that it sold a poster showing “early warning signs of fascism,” and they told us that the museum no longer carries the poster.
>
> The list was originally created by Laurence Britt in 2003, for an article published by Free Inquiry magazine (a publication for secular humanist commentary and analysis).

The original, non-cropped picture shows a price tag. In addition, the small text at the bottom reads (more visible in [this other photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueIuw.jpg) from [this Imgur gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5rTF.jpg)): "Lawrence W. Britt writes about the common signs of fascism":

> [image: all the text in the question, plus "fraudulent elections". Price tag cut off, 10 something dollars]

[Facism Anyone?](http://www.hartford-hwp.com/archives/27/076.html) has (a quote of) the article written by Britt.